# How would a professional flash this?

Tags: roof, trim, flashing

I could really use some professional advise here. I removed a piece of rotten trim I found while cleaning the gutters. The problem is pretty apparent in the photos with the gutter removed. Water followed the roof at the bottom of the rake and found its way in because there was really nothing stopping it.

How would a professional have avoided this???

I am not a carpenter and my best thought solution is not pretty. (continue the step flashing down to the end of the rake board, and cut a piece of trim to fit under it) this would leave about a half inch gap between the rake board and the flashing and would not be too pretty as you can imagine. That solution would carry the rain water over the end of the gutter also which I would like to avoid. You will also notice that a triangle piece of trim would just barely cover the opening at the top of the corner molding. (not good)

I don't trust myself to come up with the best solution here. Does anybody have some sound professional advise? [image: pic1] [image: pic2] [image]

Answer (score 5):

The term to research is *kick out flashing*. It's used when a roof line butts up against a vertical surface near the edge. It sends the water away from the vertical edge into the gutter. Example:

[image]

Comment: A useful addition, because it will divert a lot of the bulk water from the problem area, but not a comprehensive water management solution.

Comment: @benrudgers IMHO, a 'professional' would never design a roof's slant to abut a vertical service in the first place. :)

Comment: Most single family residential work in the US is not designed by licensed designed professionals. Among the projects which are, few retain the architect for construction observation. Among those, it is only a select few where the client will pay to have the architect spend enough time on site to have a reasonable chance to catch this sort of thing.

Comment: @benrudgers I agree. We build a lot of ugly houses with impractical roof lines in this country. My favorite quote about how to tell if an architect designed a house was from a local architect we hired. He said "look at the roof line...if an architect designed the house, the roof is a major focus and was given though early in the process. If not, the entire roof is an afterthought of bizarre dormers and abutments."

Comment: The project looks like an addition (or actually several). IMO, there's nothing magical about an architect designing a single family residence - many of the major US use architects on the front end of the development process. The issue is that homebuilding has its own traditions...e.g. this site...that place more value on crown molding than technical expertise.

Comment: Kickout flashing would be great! Can anyone give any advice as to how to get it in there? From my modest understanding it will start at the vertical wall and protrude out along the roof line. Will I have to cut a slit in the Rake trim for this to happen? Or am I missing something very simple?

Comment: @Brett it looks like this roof was built over an existing one? I'm not a roofing expert, but it seems that this entire edge of the roof should have been flashed with some custom z-channel so that it was under both sets of shingles to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it right requires avoiding back-laps. That means removing some of the intersecting fascia, all of the rake trim from the triangular area and some shingles because avoiding back-laps means starting from the bottom and working all the way to the top.

For the water management plane, I'd consider self-adhered flashings placing a first layer across all corners, counter-flashing with more of it, and then counter-flashing the whole layer with brake-metal fabrications followed by sealing all joints with a high quality sealant.

Again all working from bottom to top while making sure that water flows out, not in. The key to proper flashing is thinking about how water flows.

Comment: And then you get to do the rest of the gutters, too.